# Cannot receive correct object when returning it from the function

Tags: go

In the function `Demo1_CallFindAll()` I am trying to return an object from a database.

In `foo()` I cannot see it after using Print. However, I call the `Demo1_CallFindAll` function and can see an array of objects in it.

Please explain why and correct my code.

```
func foo(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    w.Header().Set("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*")
    w.Header().Set("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Content-Type")
    var tags = Demo1_CallFindAll()
    fmt.Println(tags) // Here I see nothing
    js, err := json.Marshal(tags)
    if err != nil {
        http.Error(w, err.Error(), http.StatusInternalServerError)
        return
    }

    w.Header().Set("Content-Type", "application/json")
    w.Write(js)

    json.NewEncoder(w).Encode("OKOK")
}

func Demo1_CallFindAll()(products []entities.Product)  {
    db,err:=config.GetMySQLDB()
    if err !=nil{
        fmt.Println(err)
    }else{
        productModel := models.ProductModel{
            Db:db,
        }
        products,err := productModel.FindAll()
        if err !=nil{
            fmt.Println(err)
        }else{
fmt.Println(products)//[{1 Nokia1 10 2 true} {2 Nokia2 11 22 false}]

            fmt.Println("Product List")
        }
    }
    return
}
```

Comment: it could be there is an error occurred during `Demo1_CallFindAll()` call. try to print the products on block `if err !=nil{`

Answer (score 2):

The bug is in this line: `products,err := productModel.FindAll()`. You used named return parameters in the `Demo1_CallFindAll()` functions. Named returned parameters are initialized to their zero value(ref: https://golang.org/doc/effective_go.html#named-results).

But in the line `products,err := productModel.FindAll()`, you created a new variable (by `:=`) `products` and set results in it, not in the return parameter `products`. That's why you can not see anything in the `foo()` functions. To solve it, change `:=` to `=`, `products,err = productModel.FindAll()`.